# I cannot change Storyboard on Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am having a problem because I was want to change screen on Corona but I cannot. 
I have my main.lua with the main menu with 2 buttons. 'Play' and 'About'. I also have an 'about.lua'.

What I want is when you press About it will got to the about section (about.lua)
All I have so far is

```
local storyboard = require ( "storyboard" )

local function about(event)
    storyboard:newScene( "about" )
end

local about = widget.newButton
    {
        top = 280,
        width = 320,
        height = 66,
        defaultFile = "about.png",
        overFile = "aboutdown.png",
        onRelease = about
}
```

Could you please help? All I want is my Main page to go to the About page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the scene about yet? Also to change scenes, you want to use the `storyboard.gotoScene()`

Check out these docs, they will run you through how to do it. http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/

Answer (score 0):

You surely get error from this since storyboard has functions not methods, so don't use "colon" on it. Also you have to keep the return value from newScene. Example:

```
local function about(event)
    sceneAbout = storyboard.newScene( "about" )
    local function sceneAbout:createScene(event) 
        ...
    end
    ... other scene methods enterScene, exitScene, etc ...
    storyboard.gotoScene(sceneAbout)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is wrong,

local storyboard = require ( "storyboard" )

local function about(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene( "about" )
end

```
local about = widget.newButton
{
    top = 280,
    width = 320,
    height = 66,
    defaultFile = "about.png",
    overFile = "aboutdown.png",
    onRelease = about
}
```

I hope that You are creating your buttons in the create scene.

One more advice is don't use storyboard, please use the composer it s very efficient. Have a look at this http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/index.html